# C# Username and password login box

Tags: c#, sql-server, project

I am attaching log in module in my form. I am getting problem in this because login form has to show before the other mainform so user can be authenticated. I am using VS 2005, i have two forms now

1) Login 2) MainForm
I just want to show login form before mainform and close(not hide) login form after authentication. Is there any way? Previously i worked splash screen and solved it with threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Windows Forms application? Could you not open a new instance of the LoginForm when the MainForm is instantiated from the main method?

You could then use the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to determine whether the user is authenticated and call Dispose() on the LoginForm afterwards.

```
   public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DialogResult dr = new DialogResult ();
            LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm ();
            dr = loginForm.ShowDialog();
            if ( dr == DialogResult.OK )
            {
               //user is authenticated
            }
            else 
            {
               //user isn't
            }
        }
    }
```

And your login form could look like this

```
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (DoAuthentication)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I agree with both, but i am asked to do through Form. I would have attached dialogue. :)

Comment: That is a Windows Form application.

Comment: Yes it is a windows form application

Comment: No problem I had to look it up myself!